# An idiom for someone vainly full of themselves

Tags: idiom-request

In Arabic, there's an expression likening an arrogant delusional person to a lizard.

> As long as a lizard doesn't see the clog, it will continue to think itself a crocodile.

It's common practice in Muslim countries to kill lizards usually using clogs and similar footwear.

Is there any English expression that goes along those lines?

Answer (score 1):

"all that and a bag of chips"

A common idiom used for people who are full of themselves, arrogant, vain, and/or think very highly of themselves, often delusional so, is "all that and bag of chips," like about a guy who's like that, you might say, "He thinks he's all that and a bag of chips." What's funny is such a person may even say about themselves, "I'm all that and a bag of chips." Also, if you really truly find a person to be especially fantastic and wonderful, you can say, "He's all that and a bag of chips," as opposed to saying he "thinks" he is, which is what you say when conveying he's not worthy of all the enormous praise he gives himself, that he's pompous, arrogant, and vain but doesn't have the goods to back it up.

Comment: Never heard that, is it dialect?

Comment: You haven't? Hmm. Maybe it's an Americanism. Come to think of it, it probably is since what Americans call "chips" (i.e., "potato chips," which are "crisps" to non-Americans) isn't what others call "chips" (i.e., what Americans call "fries"). Anyway, "all that and a bag of chips" is an extremely common expression in America and will be understood by pretty much everyone in America. Now do Brits, Aussies, Kiwis, etc. have "all that and a bag of crisps" as an equivalent idiomatic expression? That, I don't know, so OP should maybe not use this idiom when communicating with non-Americans.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman It's not unknown in the UK, but is definitely recognised as being American in origin.

Answer (score 1):

A man who thinks he is much better or more important than he really is, is sometimes said to be "up himself". Also, he may "think his s**t doesn't stink". Both expressions are very informal. I have heard them in Australia; I don't know how common they are in other places.

Answer (score 0):

A phrase you may hear is "full of himself". Has endless possibilities for enhancing the rudeness quotient, e.g.

"He's a bit full of himself, isn't he?"

"Full of s**t, you mean."

"Yes, that's what I said, isn't it?"

And so on.